# Parameterize the following curves.

Tags: vectors, 3d, curves

a) y = $2x^2$ for x ∈ [0, 2]

---

b) the line segment from (0,0,2) to (0,0,5)

---

c) $(\frac xa)^2$ + $(\frac yb)^2$ = 1

Sorry about the form, I wasn't sure how to do some signs.

I know the basic idea of parameterization - which is a vector representation of a curve in 2D or 3D. (1D curve -> 2D or 3D).

I also know that all curves in 2D are defined by: **r**(t) = < t , f(t) >

So for a), I tried to sub x=t for the x component and y=f(t) for y component, getting **r**(t) = < t , $t^2$ >.

For b), I had no idea what to do, so i created a vector with the two given points and was lost since there.

For c), I re-arranged for y, then subbed x=t and y=f(t), getting 
**r**(t)= < t , ${\sqrt(1-\frac xa)}^2 *b $

Again, sorry for the bad form, but can anyone guide me on what I need to do / what I did wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to typeset equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: b) you are on the right track.  $(x,y,z) = P + \mathbf u t$ is a parametric equation for a line given a point on the line $P,$ direction vector $\mathbf u$  c) when dealing with conics, think trigonometric functions.

Comment: Hmm, so for b) my vector that I created <0,0,3> is the direction vector and any of the two points can be the position vector? So assume I choose the first point, (0,0,2). Would the parameterization be:
x=0
y=0
z=2+3t ?